# How can I migrate from MySQL database to WordPress format database

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am new to WordPress.

How can I display old MySQL database tables data on WordPress without changing the default WordPress database structure?

I have a few tables which contain articles, how can I use those table's data to display as posts in Wordpress?
[image]

Comment: You don't have nearly enough information for us to be helpful.  Please add a description of your current table structure.

Answer (score 0):

It's not as easy as you think. it depends on your theme options.
If I were you, I did like this:

1. Create a sample post in WordPress
2. Export this sample post from wp-admin > tools >export
3. Create an XML from old database like this exported xml
4. Import it to WordPress from wp-admin > tools > import